# Matlab curve fitting lines trough letters with image processing

Tags: matlab, image-processing, curve-fitting

For a project i am trying to make a reference trajectory writing some sort of handwritten font. Therefore I am using .png files for all the letters, for example:

[image: letter a i am trying to fit]

So what i want to do in Matlab is something like this: (but than neater and not done with paint)

[image]

Meaning the red line should be a single line through the letter.

I have already tried using:
bwboundaries: this gives me the boundary and i cannot really see how this will give me the "average"

[image: result with bwboundaries]

houghlines:  does not give the result i want (although close)

[image]

code bwboundaries:

```
BW = imbinarize(I,'adaptive','Sensitivity',1);
BW = imcomplement(BW)
[IM_b,~,~,IM_a] = bwboundaries(BW,'holes');
for i = 1:length(IM_b)
plot(IM_b{i}(1:end,2),-IM_b{i}(1:end,1)); hold on;
end
```

code houghlines:

```
BW = imbinarize(I,'adaptive','Sensitivity',1);
BW = imcomplement(BW)
[H,T,R] = hough(BW);
imshow(H,[],'XData',T,'YData',R,...
'InitialMagnification','fit');
xlabel('\theta'), ylabel('\rho');
axis on, axis normal, hold on;

P  = houghpeaks(H,5,'threshold',ceil(0.3*max(H(:))));
x = T(P(:,2)); y = R(P(:,1));
plot(x,y,'s','color','white');

lines = houghlines(BW,T,R,P,'FillGap',2,'MinLength',25);
figure, imshow(I), hold on
max_len = 0;
for k = 1:length(lines)
xy = [lines(k).point1; lines(k).point2];
plot(xy(:,1),xy(:,2),'LineWidth',2,'Color','green');

% Plot beginnings and ends of lines
plot(xy(1,1),xy(1,2),'x','LineWidth',2,'Color','yellow');
plot(xy(2,1),xy(2,2),'x','LineWidth',2,'Color','red');

% Determine the endpoints of the longest line segment
len = norm(lines(k).point1 - lines(k).point2);
if ( len > max_len)
max_len = len;
xy_long = xy;
end
end
```

Comment: I am not an expert, but you might to look at [skeletonization](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/images/skeletonization.html)

Comment: Maybe that will give a good result, however i think it will give a very pixelated result. I will try it soon

Comment: So i used the bwmorph function, however i quickly noticed the 'thin' function worked better than the 'skel' function. This resulted in the following results (a is the same as before, b is a higher resolution image): https://imgur.com/a/Hl7nR Still not exactly what i wanted however....